# Swift: Remove constraints that affecting or hooking to an UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

Any way to remove constraints that are effecting to an UIView?
In this example is a button (UIButton).

```
topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .LessThanOrEqual, toItem: rowView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 12.0)
bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: rowView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -7.0)
rowView.addConstraints([topConstraint,bottomConstraint])
```

Two constraints were added to rowView. rowView has many constraints and
I want to remove all constraints that are hooking with item: button.

Answer (score 4):

you can remove all constraints using:

```
[button removeConstraints:button.constraints];
```

and don't forget to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO`

```
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

Comment: I've tried this way but didn't work because button don't have any contraint. these contraints have added to rowview. `rowView.addConstraints([topConstraint,bottomConstraint])
` Rowview has many constraints. All i want is remove contraints are effecting to button.

Comment: Well, constraints are a two way thing, if it affects button, it is listed in its constraints, except those involving one view only. Like width or height... But, alternatively you can remove your button from its super view (by calling `button.removeFromSuperView`) and add it back to the super view to simulate removing constraints. or you can keep outlets to the constraints and remove them accordingly.

Comment: As a side note: removeFromSuperview(button) then rowView.addSubview(button). It works like a charm for me. :-)